# Best way to implement pagination in java

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, pagination

I am using hibernate api's `query.setMaxResults(maxResults)` & `query.setFirstResult(firstResult)` methods to implement pagination. `MS SQLServer 2012 sp1` is the DB that I am using for the project.

Following is the sample query:

```
SELECT a.c1, b.c2, b.c3 FROM Person as a WITH(NOLOCK), Address as b WITH(NOLOCK) where <condition> ORDER BY a.c1
```

How does the `query.setMaxResults(maxResults)` & `query.setFirstResult(firstResult)` methods work? Will it fetch all the data from DB and then filter it from the `result-set` based on first and max parameter? Or will it fetch only the number of result based on `max-result` value from the `first-result` index?

Users feel that the application is taking some time to update the UI with data. So which is the recommended way to implement pagination? Do I need to go with stored procedure or some other means to improve the performance? Kindly advice.

**update:**
When user selects page 1 following query is executed:

```
SELECT top 200 a.c1, b.c2, b.c3 FROM Person as a WITH(NOLOCK), Address as b WITH(NOLOCK) where <condition> ORDER BY a.c1 - executed with 2502540 ms
```

When user selects page 30 following query is executed:

```
SELECT top 6000 a.c1, b.c2, b.c3 FROM Person as a WITH(NOLOCK), Address as b WITH(NOLOCK) where <condition> ORDER BY a.c1 - executed with 34220186 ms
```

So its clear that time is proportional to page number. Is there a way to maintain a constant execution speed regardless of page number? Since we always fetch same number of records.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hiberante `.setMaxResults()` and `.setFirstResult()` are settings, which will be applied based on the DB Engine used an the Dialect selected.

In most cases, this will do the expecting behavior: **paging on the DB server side**. And it is really the best way how to get pages for your client (application).

In some cases, when older DB engines do not support paging, Hibernate will try to do at least the best... e.g. to take TOP 100 rows, if only 5th page with 20 rows is required (I remember with some Sybase version or SQL Server 2000)

The real SQL Statement is driven by the Dialect. E.g. different could be paging on SQL Server 2008 and SQL 2012...

*And yes, this is the correct way how to do paging with Hibernate...*